# surface area in ${\mathbb{R}}^n$

Tags: calculus, area, volume, spheres, monte-carlo

Let the surface
$E_2 = \{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in{\mathbb{R}}^3 : x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=1, x_1^2+x_2^2\leq \frac{2}{3}, x_1^2\leq \frac{1}{3} \}.$
We want to compute the surface area $a(E_2)$ of $E_2.$ That is,
$$a(E_2)=\iint_{E_2} d\sigma = 
2\iint_{{\mathbb{B}}_2} \frac{dx_1 dx_2}{\sqrt{1-x_1^2-x_2^2}}, \text{where} \ {\mathbb{B}}_2=\{x_1^2+x_2^2\leq 2/3, x_1^2\leq 1/3\}.$$
We tried Monte Carlo, i.e. we uniformly generate enough points on the sphere $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=1$ and we count how many times are in the set ${\mathbb{B}}_2.$ If I am correct, the probability is 1/3, so $a(E_2)$ must be equal to $V_2(1) = 4\pi/3.$ I am looking for a rigorous proof.
One idea to compute the previous integral explicit is to separate ${\mathbb{B}}_2$ to the two triangles
\begin{equation*} 
\begin{split}
T_1=\{(x,y):0\leq x\leq 1/\sqrt{3}, -x\leq y\leq x\} \\
T_2=\{(x,y):-1/\sqrt{3}\leq x\leq 0, x\leq y\leq -x\}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
and two (symmetric) polar regions,
\begin{equation*} 
\begin{split}
P_1=\{(r,\theta):0\leq r \leq \sqrt{2/3},\ \pi/4 \leq \theta\leq 3\pi/4\},\\ 
P_2=\{(r,\theta):0\leq r \leq \sqrt{2/3},\ 5\pi/4 \leq \theta\leq 7\pi/4\}.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
In fact I want to find $a(E_{n-1})$ where $E_{n-1}$ is the surface,
$$E_{n-1} = \big\{{\bf x}=(x_i)_i\in{\mathbb{R}}^n:x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots +x_n^2=1,\\ x_1^2+\cdots +x_{n-1}^2\leq (n-1)/n,...,\\ x_1^2+x_2^2\leq 2/n,\\ x_1^2\leq 1/n \big\}. $$
By inspection we get $a(E_{n-1})=V_{n}$ where $V_n:$ the volume of  $n-$dimensional unit sphere.

Any hint for the rigorous proof either for the case $n=3$ or for the general case?